# Use Php dropdown values to select mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php...i need help.
I have 5 tables in my sql database,
I would like to create a dropdown that basing on the value of the dropdown, then a specific table/ view is selected..please guide me..
Thank you.

Below is my php script..

**DATA QUERY** **By:**   Country District County/ Municipality Sub-County/ Municipality

```
//select database
MySQL_SELECT_db('edudata',$getconnected);

//creating query to excute on the MySQL dbms
$query="SELECT * FROM ;";
// Excute the query above
$erecords=MySQL_Query($query, $getconnected); 

echo '<table align="center" cellspacing="3" bgcolor="#d3dbde"     cellpadding="3" width="70%"> <tr><td align="left"><b>District</b></td><td align="left"><b>County/ Municipality</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number of Schools</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number of Schools</b></td><td  align="left"><b>Number of Female Teachers
</b></td> <td align="left"><b>No. of Male Teachers</b><td align="left">  <b>Female Enrollment</b></td><td align="left"><b>Male Enrollment</b></td>  </tr>';

While ($emprecord=MySQL_fetch_array($erecords))


{
Echo '<tr bgcolor="#f6f6f6"><td align="left">'.$emprecord['District'].    '</td><td align="left">'. $emprecord['County_Municipality']. '</td><td   align="left">'. $emprecord['No_of_schools']. '</td><td align="left">'.   $emprecord['Female_Teachers']. '</td><td align="left">'.   $emprecord['Male_Teachers'].'</td><td align="left">'.   $emprecord['Female_Enrolment'].'</td><td align="left">'.    emprecord['Male_Enrollment'].'</td></tr>';


}
echo '</tables>';



MySQL_Close($getconnected);
```

?>

After Applying your solution, with code below, In get the errors stated in the comments.

```
<?php 
 $getconnected=mysql_connect('localhost','**','**', 'edudata');
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{
  $mytableselect=$_POST['mytableselect'];
 //select database
//MySQL_SELECT_db('edudata',$getconnected);
mysql_select_db('edudata', $getconnected);
//creating query to excute on the MySQL dbms
$query="SELECT * FROM $mytableselect ";
// Excute the query above
$erecords=mysql_query($query, $getconnected); 

echo '<table align="center" cellspacing="3" bgcolor="#d3dbde"     cellpadding="3" width="70%"> <tr><td align="left"><b>District</b></td><td align="left"><b>County/ Municipality</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number of Schools</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number of Schools</b></td><td  align="left"><b>Number of Female Teachers
</b></td> <td align="left"><b>No. of Male Teachers</b><td align="left">  <b>Female Enrollment</b></td><td align="left"><b>Male Enrollment</b></td>  </tr>';

While ($emprecord=MySQL_fetch_array($erecords))



//Echo'<tr bgcolor="#f6f6f6"><td align="left">'.$emprecord['District'].'</td><td align="left">'. $emprecord['County_Municipality']. '</td><td   align="left">'. $emprecord['No_of_schools']. '</td><td align="left">'.   $emprecord['Female_Teachers']. '</td><td align="left">'.$emprecord['Male_Teachers'].'</td><td align="left">'.$emprecord['Female_Enrolment'].'</td><td align="left">'.emprecord['Male_Enrollment'].'</td></tr>';
Echo '<tr bgcolor="#f6f6f6"><td align="left">'.$emprecord['District']. '</td><td align="left">'. $emprecord['County_Municipality']. '</td><td align="left">'. $emprecord['No_of_schools']. '</td><td align="left">'. $emprecord['Female_Teachers']. '</td><td align="left">'. $emprecord['Male_Teachers'].'</td><td align="left">'. $emprecord['Female_Enrolment'].'</td><td align="left">'. $emprecord['Male_Enrollment'].'</td></tr>';

echo'</tables>';



MySQL_Close($getconnected);

}

?>
```

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: <form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="query.php">
  <p><b> DATA QUERY</b><strong> By: </strong>
    <select name="summeries" id="summeries">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">Country</option>
      <option value="2">District</option>
      <option value="3">County/ Municipality</option>
      <option value="4">Sub-County/ Municipality</option>
    </select>
  </p> 

  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Query" />
</form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked the magic for me.

```
<?php
$dbLink = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usr', 'passd');
mysqli_select_db('edudata', $dbLink);
$mytableselect=$_POST['mytableselect'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $mytableselect";
$result = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

// Print the column names as the headers of a table
echo "<table><tr>";
for($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    $field_info = mysqli_fetch_field($result, $i);
    echo "<th>{$field_info->name}</th>";
}

// Print the data
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $_column) {
        echo "<td>{$_column}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML CODE:**

```
  <form action="newpage.php" method="post">
    <select name="mytableselect" >
    <option value="tablename1"> Table Name 1 </option>
    <option value="tablename2"> Table Name 2 </option>
    <option value="tablename3"> Table Name 3 </option>
    <option value="tablename4"> Table Name 4 </option>
    <option value="tablename5"> Table Name 5 </option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Select Table">
    </form>
```

In the value attribute you should use your table names instead of `tablename1`, `tablename2`,...

**PHP CODE:** [newpage.php]

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $mytableselect=$_POST['mytableselect'];
 //select database
MySQL_SELECT_db('edudata',$getconnected);

//creating query to excute on the MySQL dbms
$query="SELECT * FROM $mytableselect ";
// Excute the query above
$erecords=MySQL_Query($query, $getconnected); 

echo '<table align="center" cellspacing="3" bgcolor="#d3dbde"     cellpadding="3" width="70%"> <tr><td align="left"><b>District</b></td><td align="left"><b>County/ Municipality</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number of Schools</b></td><td align="left"><b>Number of Schools</b></td><td  align="left"><b>Number of Female Teachers
</b></td> <td align="left"><b>No. of Male Teachers</b><td align="left">  <b>Female Enrollment</b></td><td align="left"><b>Male Enrollment</b></td>  </tr>';

While ($emprecord=MySQL_fetch_array($erecords))


{
Echo '<tr bgcolor="#f6f6f6"><td align="left">'.$emprecord['District'].    '</td><td align="left">'. $emprecord['County_Municipality']. '</td><td   align="left">'. $emprecord['No_of_schools']. '</td><td align="left">'.   $emprecord['Female_Teachers']. '</td><td align="left">'.   $emprecord['Male_Teachers'].'</td><td align="left">'.   $emprecord['Female_Enrolment'].'</td><td align="left">'.    emprecord['Male_Enrollment'].'</td></tr>';


}
echo '</tables>';



MySQL_Close($getconnected);

}

?>
```